# Getting IE script Error in PrimeFaces multiple upload

Tags: java, javascript, primefaces

I have create a JSF application and Its having three tabs.
I have used primefaces multiple upload component in my application.

**Error**

I can able to upload multiple file but I am getting IE script error in following scenario.

- navigate to another tab when the files uploading

**Expecting**

- I want avoid the IE script error.
- don't allow to any other process up to complete the upload process.

Comment: Why don't you prevent navigation while upload in progress ?

Comment: if I navigate to another tab the upload process will interrupt.

Comment: so try to disable the tabs while upload in progress, and enable them back oncomplete of the upload....

Comment: ok thanks daniel i will let u know after done.